# (Python) What is the proper nomenclature for this so I can search for and learn about it?

Tags: python, class, parameters, python-2.x

Sorry for the poor title. I really have no idea how to describe this to a search engine to find out how it works.

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, contents=None):
        self.contents = contents
```

Specifically, the `contents=None` parameter.

I've been studying Python for about 2 months now, and that part semi-blows my mind. Any help or redirection to a similar, previously asked question will be *very* appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's a [Default Argument Value](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values) for a [Keyword Argument](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments).

They're pretty straightforward, as long as they're not a [mutable object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument) like a list or dictionary.

Just in case it was the `__init__` method throwing you off -- it's the instance method of a class that gets automatically called when the instance is created. Any arguments you pass when you call the class to create a new instance, like

```
myclass = MyClass(contents='the_contents')
```

or

```
myclass = MyClass('the_contents')
```

in your example, are passed to the `__init__` method.

Answer (score 3):

This just means that "contents" is a parameter to be passed on when creating an instance, and that it has a default value, "None", used when the parameter is not given.

Those two ways of creating instances produces the same thing :

```
 b = MyClass()

 c = MyClass(None)
```

The best reading about Python, from the beginning, is probably the "dive" http://diveintopython.net/

Answer (score 1):

When you define a method you can assign default values for its arguments. In this example contents is None unless you pass other value to it in constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at [Keyword Arguments](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments). The link is to Python documentation which explains them in quite alot of detail.